# Data-defined size legend only showing size in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, fields-attributes, legend

I am having issues getting a legend set up in QGIS 3.34.1 for a point layer that is colored based on one attribute (population class) and then sized based on another attribute (population). I have gone through the steps of getting the data-defined size set up and everything looks fine in the layer list, but when I open a layout and add a legend, only the size symbols are visible.

You can see in the first figure below that the size part of the legend is showing up, but not the color patches  - the text for the color groups do show up though.

[image: legend only showing size]

[image: Data defined attribute set up]

I can overwrite the symbols in the legend (legend-item-properties-custom symbol) but that is tedious, and I think what I am trying to do is what the data-defined size behavior is supposed to accomplish.